# Is there a way to access T.Method() in a new instance of T in a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method

```
class Program {
    Character CreateChar<T>() where T : new() {
        T DChar = new T();
        Character Char = new Character {
            Name = DChar.Name,
            Health = DChar.Health
        };
        return Char;
    }
    public static void Main() {
        Character Char1 = CreateChar<Mage>();
    }
}
```

Where I have a Character class, and that has the basic stuff like Name, Health, ect.

```
class Character {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}
```

But (this is like a game) I have some set types like "Mage".

```
class Mage {
    public int Health {
        get {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

So my idea was to make a generic method "CreateChar" so I can pass Mage to it like so in Main:

```
 Character Char1 = CreateChar<Mage>();
```

However I can't seem to access DChar.Name or DChar.Health since "T does not contain a definition for 'Health'". So, is there a way to access the T method? Or is there just a better way of handling this?

In fact, now that I see it, "CreateChar();" is invalid as well because "an object reference is required for a nonstatic field". So I guess my question is, what is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the declaration `Character void CreateChar<T>()` supposed to be? That won't compile. Please fix your question so it make sense. Please also be more specific about what you're trying to do. Provide a good [mcve] that shows exactly the relevant types and their important members, explain what you want the generic method to do, why you believe that it _should_ be a generic method, what you've tried so far, why that didn't work, and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: In a generic method, you can only access the methods defined by the constraint on `T` (unless you use reflection or type checking/casting, both of which defeat the purpose of generics). If you constrain `T` to a `Character` (which I think you *have* to do to access `Name` and `Health`), then it should work (please post the `Character` class with relevant properties). But then in order to pass it a `Mage`, you'd have to have `Mage` inherit from `Character` (or, possibly better, have both `Character` and `Mage` implement `ICharacter`, and then constrain `T` to that, like: `where T : ICharacter`)

Comment: @LardPies - `Character void CreateChar<T>()` is still not valid. A function can either return a type or `void`, but not both.

Comment: if your Mage and other game classes don't inherit a common base class you won't be able to handle this genetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a generic method, you can only access the methods defined by the constraint on `T` (unless you use reflection or type checking/casting, both of which defeat the purpose of generics). If you constrain `T` to a `Character` (which I think you *have* to do to access `Name` and `Health`), then it should work (please post the `Character` class with relevant properties). But then in order to pass it a `Mage`, you'd have to have `Mage` inherit from `Character`.

Here's what I mean; first create an interface that defines properties that *all* characters will have (i.e. all public properties, methods, and events):

```
public interface ICharacter
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; }
    int Health { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can create a base class called `Character` that implements the interface::

```
public class Character :  ICharacter
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Default Character";
    public int Health { get; set; } = 5;
    public string Description { get; protected set; } = "Default Description";
}
```

Next we create some character types that inherit the `Character` class:

```
public class Mage : Character
{
    public Mage()
    {
        Name = "Default Mage";
        Description = "Someone who uses or practices magic " + 
            "derived from supernatural or occult sources.";
    }
}

public class Elf : Character
{
    public Elf()
    {
        Name = "Default Elf";
        Description = "A supernatural creature of folk tales, " + 
            "typically represented as a small, elusive figure " + 
            "in human form with pointed ears, magical powers, " + 
            "and a capricious nature.";
    }
}
```

So now we can constrian our generic type `T` to the `ICharacter` interface, and we can access the `Name` and `Health` properties:

```
class Program
{
    T CreateChar<T>() where T : ICharacter, new()
    {
        var result = new T();
        result.Name += " (created in 'CreateChar' method)";  // Modify a property
        return result;
    }

    // Rest of class omitted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain `T` to an interface or a base class that contains the method you want to call.

I think you are looking at a factory pattern here. Does this help?

```
public class Character 
{
    protected Character(string name, int health)
    {
        Name=name;
        Health=health;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}

public class Mage : Character
{
    public Mage() : base("Evil Mage", 5)
    {
        this.Mana = 10;
    }

    public int Mana { get; set; }
}

public class Paladin : Character
{
    public Paladin() : base("Holy Paladin", 8)
    {
        this.Shield = 2;
    }

    public int Shield { get; set; }
}

public static class ChatacterFactory
{
    public static TChar Create<TChar>(string name) where TChar : Character, new()
    {
        var result = new TChar();
        result.Name = name;
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mage mage = ChatacterFactory.Create<Mage>("Boom Mage");
        Paladin paladin = ChatacterFactory.Create<Paladin>("White Knight");
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understood him right the problem is that he cannot write the charclasses himself

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you right one of these should work for you:

```
//case 1

class Character1
{
    static Character1 CreateChar<T>(T character) where T : CommonGameCharecterClassOrInterface, new()
    {
        Character1 achar = new Character1
        {
            Name = character.Name,
            Health = character.Health
        };
        return achar;
    }
}

class Character2
{
    static Character2 CreateChar(dynamic character)
    {
        Character2 achar = new Character2
        {
            Name = character.Name,
            Health = character.Health
        };
        return achar;
    }
}

//case 2

class Character3
{
    static Character3 CreateChar<T>() where T : CommonGameCharecterClassOrInterface, new()
    {
        T character = new T();
        Character3 achar = new Character3
        {
            Name = character.Name,
            Health = character.Health
        };
        return achar;
    }
}

class Character4
{
    static Character4 CreateChar<T>() where T : new()
    {
        dynamic character = new T();
        Character4 achar = new Character4
        {
            Name = character.Name,
            Health = character.Health
        };
        return achar;
    }
}
```