# how to set template in c#

Tags: c#, templates, set

how do I set id in Sprite from the template templa

```
public class templa<T> where T : class , new(){
    public T CreateMe(){
        T temp = new T();
        shortInt si
        si.Set(2, 2);
        //T needs to have id as shortInt else it won't work
        
        temp.id = si; // temp = si// doesn't work either
        return temp;
    }
}
public struct shortInt{
    public short s;
    public int i;
    public void Set(short s, int i){
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Sprite here has id this is what I'm trying to achieve to change id with template

```
public class Sprite{
    public Sprite(){}
    public shortInt id;
    set{
        id = value;
    }
}
```

I was searching the web and found only do it with { get; set; } I'm clueless here

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297919/is-there-a-way-to-access-t-method-in-a-new-instance-of-t-in-a-generic-method answer your question?

Comment: no the answer answered my question your hiperlink answers the new T()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  [where(generic type constraint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

code like this

```cs
 public class Templat<T> where T :
     Sprite, new()  //constraint in here
    {
        public T CreateMe()
        {
            T temp = new T();
            shortInt si = new shortInt();
            si.Set(2, 2);

            temp.id = si;
            return temp;
        }

    }

    public struct shortInt
    {
        public short s;
        public int i;
        public void Set(short s, int i)
        {
            this.s = s;
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    public class Sprite
    {
        public Sprite() { }
        public shortInt id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: got it thanks this:

    public class Templat<T> where T : Sprite, new()

has done it's job I was looking your code quite while to find the problem thanks